# How to shift between two same windows using keyboard keys in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have opened Chrome browser in Ubuntu: a normal window and an incognito window.
I want to shift from normal window to incognito window.
I have tried `Alt+Tab` but it shifts to new windows(i.e. from Chrome browser to File Manager).
[image: check image ...]

`Ctrl+Tab` is used for shifting between tabs in current window(i.e. tabs in Chrome Normal window)

Please do let me know if there is any shortkey for it.

Comment: Do You use left alt? I think that more appropriate about this question will be https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: yes i've used left alt key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the short key to switch between different windows of same application.

- Use `Alt + F6` to switch.
- We also can use `Ctrl + Alt`, `downward arrow` and `left or right keys`

But I do prefer `Alt + F6`

Answer (score 7):

Use

> **Alt + `**

(usually the ` symbol is above the tab key)

to switch between windows of a same application.

Comment: For me only this works and I see no vote up for this. Strange. +1 from me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alt + Tab

Switch between currently-open windows. Press Alt + Tab and then release Tab (but continue to hold Alt). Press Tab repeatedly to cycle through the list of available windows which appears on the screen. Release the Alt key to switch to the selected window.

Ctrl + Alt + Tab

Switch between currently-open windows in all Workspaces. Press Tab repeatedly to cycle through the list of available windows which appears on the screen. Release the Ctrl and Alt keys to switch to the selected window.

Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right Cursor

Lets you quickly switch between your Workspaces.

These might not work on every machine, but are reasonably common:

Alt+F7

Moves the current window (can be moved with mouse or keyboard).

Alt+F8

Resizes current window (again, can be moved with mouse or keyboard).

Alt+F9

Minimises current window.

Alt+F10

Maximises current window.

Alt+Space

Brings up window menu with with 'Always on Top' and 'Minimise' and 'Maximise' and above commands.

These might change depending on the application you're using, but work for most common applications:

Alt+F5

Returns window to 'normal' or previous size.

Alt+F4

Closes window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done ```Ctrl + Alt + Tab``` , ```Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right Cursor

``` and ```Alt+Tab``` but nothing works.

Comment: I've added image please check it.

Comment: the image shows the 2nd chrome as chrome tab. In this case you case use CRTL+TAB or CTRL+2

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is even possible:

Alt+Tab shifts between different windows
Ctrl+Tab shifts between different tabs within one window

So, as your normal window and incognito window are different windows, you should be able to switch between them using Alt+Tab, but as there seem to be more windows involved, you might need to repeat this action different times.

Comment: I've added image please check it.